# What are the big enhancements in the 2013 SharePoint REST/Client API?

Tags: 2010, 2013, rest, client-object-model

The MSDN mentions there are some enhancements in the REST/Client API, but the things it lists seem to already be in the 2010 APIs.  Can someone please elaborate on the new features that are NEW In 2013 and dont' exist in 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a list of everything that is new in the Client Object Model but this is an overview of the coverage area in SharePoint 2013:

- Sites, Webs, Features, Event Receivers, Site Collections
- Lists, List Items, Fields, Content Types, Views, Forms
- Files, Folders
- Users, Roles, Groups, User Profiles, Feeds
- Web Parts
- Search
- Taxonomy
- Workflow
- IRM
- E-Discovery
- Analytics
- Business Data

The stuff from search down is all new and some of the stuff from web parts up is new or enhanced.

For the REST API, everything beyond CRUD operations on list data is new to SharePoint 2013. This includes:

- Sites, Webs, Features, Event Receivers, Site Collections
- Lists, List Items, Fields, Content Types, Views, Forms, IRM
- Files, Folders
- Users, Roles, Groups, User Profiles, Feeds
- Search